# Организация DDoS атаки

Tags: ddos

Какие компоненты необходимы для организации DDoS атаки и как эти компоненты внедрить?

Comment: не совсем дорубаю. видел архитектуру ДДоС атаки. Участники: 1-атакующий 2-демоны 3-зомби-сеть. Не могу понять каким образом атакуюўий подгребает под себя демонов и как демоны в свою очередь организуют зомби-сеть. реализуется ли это все одной программой? и как в последствии атакуюўий отдает команду о начале атаки? Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Вы бы лучше поинтересовались как от них защититься.. хакеры млин=\\

Comment: что бы уметь защищаться, нужно знать, как нападают. А иначе построить качественную защиту нельзя.

Comment: Абслолютно согласен с KoVadim. изуется атака не в корыстных целях, уверяюю.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Попробую серьезно ответить)

Для начала читайте все, что найдете, по ботнетам. Создаются они обычно тихими вирями, которые сидят, никого не трогают и раз в N минут шлют запрос на "базу". База может быть одним сервером или несколькими, тогда запросы чередуются.

Когда на базе обнаруживается задание (обычно передаются в виде структуры, напр. "1/2/123.45.67.89:80/4/register.php?save=1" может означать "задача 1 (ддос), метод 2(гет) на IP 123.45.67.89 порт 80, интенсивность 4, адрес долбежки `/register.php?save=1`"), бот начинает его выполнять. Соответственно, в нем должны быть обработчики для каждого задания. Как правило, для гет- и пост- атак предварительно на сайте выбираются некэшируемые, тяжелые страницы (новости, логин, юзерские галереи и пр.).

По сути главные сложности - написание вирей (а их такого рода довольно сложно спалить, ибо поведение в "stand by" мало чем от аси отличается) и организация базы. Вторая сложность - скрыть отношение между базой и вами, ну и ботами и вами, но это проще. Особые умельцы закладывают адрес базы как результат псевдослучайного генератора, тогда в случае падения основной базы все боты перекинутся на следующий адрес. Т.о. при накрытии базы не удается идентифицировать создателя, а боты тупо меняют адрес и продолжают работу, тогда остается только громко звать на помощь каспера или человека-паука.

Ну и соответственно вирусы тут вам писать не будут, а вот организовать базу на фрихостинге вполне можно с помощью и сердечной поддержкой анонимайзеров, коих в сети не великое, но таки множество.

Ах да, защита)) Защищаемся от пинга блокировкой IP больше лимита Q запросов на T сек, от гета-поста: lvl1 та же блокировка, lvl2 проверка на кол-во одинаковых запросов (если страничка специфичная, а запросы шкалят - блок, в зависимости от опасности, IP или страницы), lvl3 эвристика всякая, капчи и прочее.

Comment: огромное спасибо. но у меня еще столько вопросов. если вы не против ответить я могу их задать...

Comment: @Pentium, я бы не сказал, что профи в этой теме, но попробовать можно) в любом случае единственное нестандартное для прогера умение - обход антивиря и вирусописательство в общем. Остальное неплохо ищется по словам "настройка сервера", "демон", "сокет" и "ботнет", ну и неплохо бы знать протоколы HTTP, CONNECT, SOCKS4/5.

Comment: Sh4dow в итоге у меня должно получится ПО. сможешь помочь? тип атаки не важен главное чтоб DDoS атака была ну думаю что http flood более распространен и легче в написании. что скажешь? надеюсь на помощь... спасибо

Comment: Сделайте ддос другим способом, без написания вирусов. Можно арендовать бот нет сеть (поискать на хакерском форуме) или же заказать саму ддос атаку (расценки по дням). Это будет дешевле и быстрее, чем писать самому. Ну а если соберетесь писать, то надо коммерческое применение искать, потому как не окупится вся эта затея!

Comment: а вообще реально написать? мне бы просто написать а использовать я ее не собираюсь.

Comment: @Pentium, тут ПО нужно великое множество) Для начала изолировать комп - олдовая (глючная, но рабочая) связка - Odysseus+FreeCap. Взять для разработок какой-нить бесплатный хостинг(т.е. +к ПО - сервер). Найти какую-нибудь крошечную библиотеку с сокетами, разобраться в ней и писать вирь. Собственно, помочь я могу по всем пунктам, кроме виря, ибо не занимался этим никогда. Контакты в профиле.

Таки да, мне все равно, что вы будете с ним делать) Люблю оружие, а кто не умеет применять, обычно сам страдает. В данном случае учтите, что хороший ддос = огромный штраф и/или 5-10 лет.

Comment: @Sh4dow не могу найти ваши контакты. напишите пожалуйста сюда.

Answer (score 34):

[DDOS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DoS-атака). Начиная со второго абзаца - теория.
Практика в большинстве случаев заключается в запуске команды ping или аналогичной. Если запущено с нескольких компов - это будет ddos.

Для винды:

1. ping -n 65000 пишем в нескольких консолях. Пояснение: в левом нижнем углу клавиатуры есть кнопочка Ctrl. Двигаясь от нее вправо, находим кнопку, внеше отличающуюся от alt, ctrl, fn и пробела. Чаще всего, на ней нарисованы четыре перекрученных квадратика. Если такой кнопки нет, выкидываем клавиатуру и покупаем следующую. Кнопка эта называется WIN. Жмем ее и, не отпуская, R. Win+R. Если ОС - Windows, откроет черный экранчик с серыми буквами. Там набираем то, что указано в самом начале. Повторяем пункт несколько раз не закрывая черный экранчик.
2. огребаем сначала от провайдера. Пояснение: провайдер(группа суровых мужиков и, редко, теток, которые весь день занимаются тем, что раздают интернет), обнаружив, что от кого-то идут пинги в диком количестве, сначала поинтересуется адресом данного абонента, потом тихонечко прекратит раздавать ему интернет и будет ждать звонка. На звонок ответит, что надо было читать пользовательское соглашение, в котором русским по белому написано, что данная деятельность незаконна.
3. потом от того, кого пинговали, потому что это именно он настучит провайдеру на вас.
4. потом от мамы, потому что мама хотела посидеть в инете, а тут такая подстава. Да еще и штраф, небось, будет.
5. ???// дальнейшая ваша судьба зависит от суровости 2,3,4, а так же от количества пакетов, которые вы успели отправить.
6. PROFIT!

Comment: да-да, в особенности опишите процесс отгребания, думаю вопрос с ддосом отпадет сам собой =)

Comment: Готово. ^___^ *троллЪлицо*

Comment: @Qzim, ну мало ли, может, интерес академический. `*`double-trollface`*`

Comment: Спасибо, улыбнуло :)

Comment: не получается добиться отказа в обслуживании даже с 10 консолями

Comment: 10 консолей - это очень мало. Это всего-то около 250 запросов в минуту.
С такой задачей справится сейчас любой(почти) хостинг. 
Запросов должно быть несколько тысяч, а то и десятков тысяч.

Поясню: если отвлечься ото всего, то условный процессор с частотой 2ГГц способен совершать 2 миллиарда простейших операций в секунду. Общение с сетевой платой и прочими устройствами, а так же работа операционки, конечно, съедают значительную часть вычислительной мощности, но общее множество порядков остается прежним.

Comment: спасибо что отзываетесь и отвечаете на мои вопросы..
а есть ли другой более продуктивный вид ДДоС? или же как можно эффективней использовать пингование?

Comment: В википедии все написано было: флуд или атака второго рода. Пинг очень маленький пакет, так что загрузка им минимальна. Можно попробовать посылать get/post запросы. Особенно, POST: они довольно жирными могут быть

Comment: Насколько мне известно "нормальные" ддос атаки проделываются с помощью бот нета, тогда уже не отхватишь ни от мамы ни от провайдера ;)

Comment: не совсем дорубаю. видел архитектуру ДДоС атаки. Участники: 1-атакующий 2-демоны 3-зомби-сеть. Не могу понять каким образом атакуюўий подгребает под себя демонов и как демоны в свою очередь организуют зомби-сеть. реализуется ли это все одной программой? и как в последствии атакуюўий отдает команду о начале атаки? 
Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: подозреваю, что "демоны" - это сервера, которые раздают указания "зомби". То есть, зомби (просто зараженные машины) с определенным интервалом подключаются к "демонам" и смотрят, нет ли там "заданий". Если есть - исполняют.
А команда отдается очень просто - на сервера демонов выкладывается файл с заданием (а может просто запись в базу, и что угодно).
Организуется ли все это одной программой? теоретически можно так сделать, но на практике - не нужно. Зачем, что бы у каждого зомби был пульт управления сетью? Да и лишние мегабайты.

Comment: благодарю за ответ. будут дополнения, убедительная просьба пишите. будет полезно почитать...

Comment: Одного компа для DDOS маловато - это будет просто DOS.